# Rails security: allowing slash as user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security

I have a Rails 3.2.21 application. One of my users has an address with a slash in it (think Main Street 321 1/2). Currently, we filter out slashes, which makes this user's address invalid in our system. How can I allow this address through without either disabling the validation for this particular address or allowing slashes globally (a huge security risk)? Is there a way I can encode the slash, put it into the database and encode it back to a slash upon retrieval?

Thank you!

Comment: Use parameters for database inserts/updates instead of building the string manually.  For most implementations of SQL I've been exposed to, this is done with `@` for named ones, and `?` for positional ones.

Comment: Looks like the call was made for you.  Slashes in addresses are valid.  But you can limit it to certain positions and constraints utilizing regex in your validator.  I am curious to know what security risks are present.  How can one XSS with slashes in the address?

Comment: Just allowing slashes opens up increased possibility for XSS (Rails is pretty good about HTML encoding everything that gets sent through, but there are several known vulnerabilities, particularly when combined with JS, and I'd rather whitelist as much as possible).

Comment: @Crisfole - Can you expand on that a bit or provide a link to more info? Thanks!

Comment: http://blog.8thlight.com/adam-gooch/2013/01/04/protect-yourself-from-sql-injection.html

Answer (score 1):

> Just allowing slashes opens up increased possibility for XSS

Not really. Slashes are not special characters in places you are likely to accidentally inject content with XSS potential (HTML, JavaScript string literals). Input validation is in any case not the correct place to be addressing injection issues.

The class of vulnerability that slashes are likely to affect is filepath injection (typically resulting in unwanted file access through directory traversal). But still the place to worry about that is where you create filepaths.

> Is there a way I can encode the slash, put it into the database and encode it back to a slash upon retrieval?

The database doesn't need to be protected from slashes. And if you did that, and there *were* any XSS or filepath problems in your code—problems that don't live in the databases—you would still be just vulnerable as before.